# Shell Script to check password has been set to Immediately and what the screen saver time is set to

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, script, screensaver

I need to create a script for checking a security posture of a machine using OPSWAT MetaAccess. They have a built-in check, however, according to them, they aren't able to check since macOS 10.13+. This seems to coordinate with a change other people have discussed on other forums where the following commands don't work anymore. OPSWAT does support checks via custom shell script and so I'm figuring out how to write that now.

The scripts that don't work anymore:

defaults read com.apple.screensaver idleTime

defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime

defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver askForPassword

defaults read com.apple.screensaver askForPassword

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which time do you need, the "get password after screensaver" time (from your first screenshot) or the "launch screensaver after inactivity" time (from your second screenshot)?

Comment: @nohillside Both, I want to ensure "get password after screensaver" is set to Immediately and that "launch screensaver after inactivity" is set to 10 mins or less.

Comment: They are in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.{screensaver,configurationprofiles.user}.UUID.plist` now (where UUID is host-specific but I don't know where it comes from).